# Debugging permission denied/rules with angularfire

Tags: angularfire

I am getting "Error: permission_denied: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data."  I am relatively sure I have a rule problem.  Is there a way to trace which client calls in angularfire failed?  The level of abstraction and ansynchronicity in this library makes it difficult to even find the function call that caused it let alone the actual firebase REST call.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Firebase console.
On left side bar, click on "Develop" to expand.
Click on "Database" option.
On main screen click on "Rules" tab.

Copy paste the below JSON in rules

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

Below is the screenshot :-

[image]